# akka.cluster.ddata.Replicator$Internal$DeltaPropagation message from clusterReceptionist replicator is dropped because it exceeds the size limit

Tags: akka, actor, sharding, distributed-system

The error message

```
Message [akka.cluster.ddata.Replicator$Internal$DeltaPropagation] 
wrapped in [akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage] 
from Actor[akka://my-app/system/clusterReceptionist/replicator#-189849616] 
to Actor[akka://my-app@10.180.102.333:2550/] was dropped. 
Discarding oversized payload sent to Some(Actor[akka://my-app@10.180.102.333:2550/]): 
max allowed size 262144 bytes.
```

DeltaPropagation definition in Akka code

```
final case class DeltaPropagation(_fromNode: UniqueAddress, reply: Boolean, deltas: Map[KeyId, Delta])
```

Thoughts and questions:

Looks like the number of deltas could be so large that it inflates the class size beyond the limit?
Can this be confirmed some how? Or event estimated looking at my settings (most of them are default)
How can I keep this list within the limits that is acceptable by akka?

I looked up the Akka sharding documentation also read about the receptionist. I was not able to find the answers there.

Comment: can you explain it more clearly